# Recreate index on column store indexed table with 35 billion rows

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

I have a big table that I need to rebuild the index. The table is configured with Clustered Column Store Index (CCI) and we realized we need to sort the data according to specific use case.

User performs date range and equality query but because the data was not sorted in the way they would like to get it back, the query is not optimal. SQL Advisory Team recommended that data are organized in right row group so query can benefit from row group elimination.

Table Description:

- Partition by Timestamp1, monthly PF
- Total Rows: 31 billion
- Est row size: 60 bytes
- Est table size: 600 GB

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [PkId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FKId1] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [FKId2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FKId3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FKId4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp1] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [Measurement1] [real] NULL,
    [Measurement2] [real] NULL,
    [Measurement3] [real] NULL,
    [Measurement4] [real] NULL,
    [Measurement5] [real] NULL,
    [Timestamp2] [datetime2](3) NULL,
    [TimeZoneOffset] [tinyint] NULL
)

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [Table1_ColumnStoreIndex] ON [dbo].[Table1] WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF)
GO
```

Environment:

- SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Ed.
- 8 Cores, 32 GB RAM
- VMWare High
  Performance Platform

My strategy is:

1. Drop the existing CCI
2. Create ordinary Clustered Row Index with the right columns, this will sort the data
3. Recreate CCI with DROP EXISTING = OFF. This will convert the existing CRI into CCI.

My questions are:

1. Does it make sense to rebuild the index or just reload the data? Reloading may take a month to complete where as rebuilding the index may take as much time either, maybe...
2. If I drop the existing CCI, the table will expand as it may not be compressed anymore?

Answer (score 0):

31 billion rows is 31,000 perfect row groups, a rowgroup is just another horizontal partitioning, so it really matters when and how you load your data. SQL 2014 supports only offline index build.

There are a few cons and pros when considering create index vs. reload:

- Create index is a single operation, so if it fails at any point you lost your progress. I would not recommend it at your data size.
- Index build will create primary dictionaries so for low cardinality dictionary encoded columns it is beneficial.
- Bulk load won't create primary dictionaries, but you can reload data if for some reason your batches fail.

Both index build and bulk load will be parallel if you give enough resources, which means your ordering from the base clustered index won't be perfectly preserved, this is just something to be aware of; at your scale of data it won't matter if you have a few overlapping rowgroups.

If your data will undergo updates/deletes and you reorganize (from SQL19 will also do it Tuple Mover) your ordering might degrade over time.

I would create a Clustered Index ordered and partition on the `date_range` column so that you have anything between 50-200 rowgroups per partition (do some experiments). Then you can create a partition aligned Clustered Columnstore Index and switch in one partition at a time, the partition switch will trigger index build so you'll get the benefit from primary dictionaries and if you end up with updates/deletes on a partition you can fix the index quality up by rebuilding the partition rather than the whole table. If you decide to use reorganize you still maintain some level of ordering, because rowgroups will only be merged within the same partition.